# Your favorite colorscheme for terminal vim with 256 colors

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'm trying to find good looking colorscheme for vim (urxvt 256 colors) editor.
There are a lot of good schemes for gvim but not for vim 256.
For this moment I've only found jellybeans https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim which is almost identical if you use it in gvim.
I also know about solarized though I don't like it very much.
What's your suggestions? What are you using in terminals that support 256 colors for vim?

Comment: You could try my colorscheme, [Apprentice](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice). It's designed to look the same in GVim/MacVim and in 256colors terminal emulators. I also provide a subset of the color palette to set your terminal emulator's colorscheme so that you don't have to change your default `TERM`.

Comment: thank you. It's quite interesting. As I see you also have disciple light theme which is also quite good.

Comment: just found tomorrow-theme https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme which is really good

Comment: https://github.com/andrwb/vim-lapis256 best one!!

Answer (score 29):

[`Gruvbox`](https://github.com/morhetz/gruvbox)

> Gruvbox is heavily inspired by badwolf, jellybeans and solarized.

[image]

[`Hybrid`](https://github.com/w0ng/vim-hybrid)

> A dark colourscheme for Vim that combines the:
>
> colour palette from Tomorrow-Night.
>
> syntax group highlighting scheme from Jellybeans
>
> Vim code from Solarized

[image]

Comment: Is this gruvbox in the terminal? For me it looks completely different when I run it with 256 colors in comparison to GUI mode ...

Comment: @Pieter-Jan i use it in terminal, http://i.imgur.com/pRBSvLv.png

Comment: I figured something was wrong. I installed gruvbox by copying the gruvbox.vim file into the "colors" folder which did not include the 256 color palette. I now installed it with Pathogen and now it looks beautiful as always. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

For me the best color schema for vim is Monokai:
[image]

You can download it here: [Vim-Monokai](https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai)

It's a very readable schema and it already exists for iTerm2 ;-)

Comment: monokai or molokai has a big issue,  can't show out the ctrl-v block

Answer (score 4):

Plugins like [CSApprox](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2390) can take the GUI color definitions and convert them to a closely matching 256-color `cterm` color palette for high-color terminals. This helps with colorschemes that otherwise only pick from the bland default 16-color terminal color palette, or only provide GUI color definitions.

Another approach is taken by [csexact](https://github.com/KevinGoodsell/vim-csexact), which modifies the (supported) terminal's palette to exactly match Vim's GUI colors.

With either approach, you can take any GUI-only colorscheme that you like and use it in the high-color terminal, too.

Comment: I'll try to experiment with these.

Comment: Note, this only works when you have vim compiled with +gui in vim less than 7.3.